# TSQL Issue with NULLIF and 0 conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am having a small issue that is causing me some grief. Something that seems logical in my head isn't working in my favor.

I allow users to "Mass Update" records and give them the ability to change one piece of data or all of it.

If the user enters a integer such as 1 in the `totalLeaders` field, it updates the value just fine.

If the user leaves the field empty, it converts it to `null` and skips that update leaving its current value just fine.

However, if I pass a `0` in that field to say that no leaders will be trained, it says its a null value and doesn't execute the `IF` statement.

I would expect `<totalLeaders>0</totalLeaders>` to not be treated as a null value and execute the `IF` statement. I would also expect `<totalLeaders></totalLeaders>` to be treated as a NULL value and `NOT` execute the `IF` statement.

Any thoughts??

```
DECLARE @totalTrainingTime INT;
DECLARE @totalTeammates INT;
DECLARE @totalLeaders INT;
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root><data><totalLeaders>0</totalLeaders><totalTeammates>2</totalTeammates><totalTrainingTime>12</totalTrainingTime></data></root>';

-- Set our variables
SELECT @totalTrainingTime = NULLIF(ParamValues.x1.value('totalTrainingTime[1]', 'INT'), ''),
       @totalTeammates = NULLIF(ParamValues.x1.value('totalTeammates[1]', 'INT'), ''),
       @totalLeaders = NULLIF(ParamValues.x1.value('totalLeaders[1]', 'INT'), '')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/data') AS ParamValues(x1);

-- Test
SELECT @totalLeaders AS leaders,
       @totalTeammates AS teammates,
       @totalTrainingTime AS trainingTime

--Do we have leaders?
IF (@totalLeaders IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Lets update the leaders because we were given a value'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'We did not update leaders because it was a NULL value... However, it was really 0 that was passed'
END

--Do we have teammates?
IF (@totalTeammates IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Lets update the teammates because we have a value'
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`NULLIF(ParamValues.x1.value('totalLeaders[1]/text()[1]', 'INT'),0)`

Comment: I don't want the value to be set to `0`if its `NULL`

Comment: This would set the value to `NULL` if it is 0 not the other way around. If it is `NULL` it will stay `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain why the value zero be appearing as `NULL`, but one option might be to convert to `VARCHAR` first:

```
@totalLeaders = CONVERT(INT, NULLIF(ParamValues.TaskChainerTask.query('Property1').value('totalLeaders[1]', 'VARCHAR(5)'),''))
```

Please have a look at [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208198/selecting-null-value-from-xml-in-sql-server) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Get it as `VARCHAR` and then `CONVERT` it if needed

```
@totalLeaders = NULLIF(ParamValues.x1.value('totalLeaders[1]', 'varchar(50)'), '')
```